# Scroll not working in FF 4

Tags: html, css

I have a table with tbody scroll It works fine in FF 3.* but not in FF 4. I had given height as 400px for the table and for tbody i gave

overflow: auto;overflow-x:hidden;

What are the changes to be done

Comment: can you put your code.so we can work with

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: I gave overflow: auto for the tbody

Comment: can you paste your code..so i can work with it and find out the solution

Comment: <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="center" style="height: 400px; " id="tab1"><thead><td>header</td></thead><tbody style="height: 400px; overflow: scroll;overflow-y:scroll:overflow-x:hidden"><td>body</td></tbody>